# Blade is not Rendering Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My page was working fine but I worked on different parts then returned to find it with only plain texts.
The extends line is working perfect with all other pages

What I tried so far:

1. Removed BOM and made sure that file is UTF-8
2. made sure @extends at the very start of the file
3. tried adding html tags
4. checked for any invalid characters
5. deleted the page and copy-pasted the code in a new one
6. made sure that other blade files in the same directory are working
   the same so no parenting problem or a directory referencing problem

My blade page code (edit.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<body>

@section('content')
    <div class="row col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 float-left">
        <div class="container">

        <form method = "post" action = "{{route('companies.update',[$company->id]) }}">
            {{csrf_field()}}

            {{-- //work around to post --}}
                  <input type ="hidden" name= "_method" value = "put"> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comapny-name">Name</label>
                        <input type="string" class="form-control" name='name' id="comapny-name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter company name" required value="{{$company->name}}">
                        <small id="helpText" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your informations with anyone else but Khalood because he is the website devloper :).</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="company-content">Description</label>
                        <textarea name='description'style = "resize: vertical" class="form-control autosize-target text-left" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter description" rows="5" >
                         {{$company->description}}</textarea>

                    </div>    
                    <div class="form-group">

                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>



          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 float-right">

            <div class="sidebar-module">
              <h4>Actions</h4>
              <ol class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="/companies/{{$company->id}}">View Companies</a></li>
              <li><a href="/companies/">All Companies</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add new member</a></li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->




   @endsection



  </body>
```

Route code from the Controller:

```
  public function edit($id)
    {
        $company = Company::where('id',$id )->first();
        return view('companies.edit',['company'=>$company]);

    }
```

Also the action line that transfer you to controller:

```
      <li><a href="/companies/{{$company->id}}/edit">Edit</a></li>
```

app.blade.php follows. It should be working fine because I'm extending it in many other pages and works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
{{-- adding the new theme css nad bootstraps we kedh --}}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        {{-- <title>Projects Managment Portal</title> --}}
        {{-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
        Not working favicon
        --}}
        <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
        <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


        <!-- CSRF Token -->
         <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

         <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
         <!-- Scripts -->

         <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>


        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        {{-- Favicons css  for the nav bar icons--}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">




</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}"><i class="fab fa-product-hunt"></i>rojacker</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                        <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/') }}"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('companies.index') }}"><i class="far fa-building"></i> Companies</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('projects.index') }}"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i> Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('tasks.index') }}"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i> Tasks</a>
                        </li>
 {{-- Admin Panel                        --}}
 @if (Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
 <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
            Admin Panel <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('projects.index') }}"><i class="far fa-building"></i>Projects</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('projects.index') }}"><i class="far fa-building"></i>Projects</a>

                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('projects.index') }}"><i class="far fa-building"></i>Projects</a>

        </div>
    </li>   
 @endif                       
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i>
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        </nav>
    <div class="container">

        @include('partials.errors')
        @include('partials.success')


        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>


    </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>



 </body>




</html>
```

And web.php part containing companies part:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){


    // Creating Special Route to allow adding new project assigned to specific company id
    Route::get('/projects/create/{company_id?}', 'ProjectsController@create');

    Route::post('/projects/adduser/', 'ProjectsController@adduser')->name('projects.adduser');

    Route::resource('companies','CompaniesController');
    Route::resource('projects','ProjectsController');
    Route::resource('roles','RolesController');
    Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');
    Route::resource('users','UsersController');
    Route::resource('comments','CommentsController');



});
```

and link to image of page :

[Page of the problem sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cg59.png)

Comment: Can we see your route for that particular blade as well as the controller that directs it to the blade?

Comment: why you add <body> ? It should be in the layout ?

Comment: @BradGoldsmith I just edited it above

Comment: @LouisR I was having some other parts as a header image for this specific blade ,but removed it as a re-desgin

Comment: I just hope you correctly name the file as `edit.blade.php` **not** `edit.php`. That fools me (for twice) in the past. Silly.

Comment: @Chay22 Yeah I found a previous answer mentioning the same solution but It's .blade.php and it was working fine and then from nothing it's not working anymore :(

Comment: Please add your `web.php` file and `app.blade.php` (layout file).

Comment: what errors or exceptions did you get? did you `dd($company);` in your edit method or even `dd($id);` before `return view...;`?

Comment: @rpm192 edited & added them above, thanks :)

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din hi ahmed, Actually I don't get any error messages,it's just plain text ,edited and added a screenshot above and nope,that the edit function in the controller   |>>>>>                                   
   public function edit($id)
    {
        $company = Company::where('id',$id )->first();
        return view('companies.edit',['company'=>$company]);
        
    }

Comment: Using git I determined when exactly it stopped rendering, it's when I added a custom theme for the front page and the rest of the website,but the new CSS is working with all other pages except for the edit page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION !

it was in the app.blade.php when migrating to new design I (without noticing) got rid of the main css file and used only bootstrap file embedded in the new template, it works for the rest of the website ,but the edit page container (I don't know why specifically) needed the original native css file,just added it and it works like a charm!

Long Answer short, I was missing this line in the header of app.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```